# Example showing L1 is not a reflexive space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I know that the $L^p$ spaces are reflexive for $1<p<\infty$. I want to explicitly show that $L^1((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ is not reflexive by finding an element of $L^1$** that is not in $L^1$. To be more precise:

There is a canonical embedding $J: X \rightarrow X^{**}$ that is given by

$$J(x)(y)=y(x)$$

I want to find an element of $L^1$** that doesn't get mapped to by $J$.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596720/l1-and-l-infty-are-not-reflexive), the top two answers have a textbook reference and an actual proof.

Comment: If the question has already been answered on this site then the correct thing to do is to mark it as a duplicate (click on "close" and then "duplicate of") and not to post an answer with a link.

Comment: Apologies, will do.