# Why does the irreflexivity of $L^1$ follow from $(L^1)'' \subsetneq L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, reflexive-space

My question is about the proof that $l^1$ is irreflexive. I have seen multiple proofs ([$L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$ are not reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596720/l1-and-l-infty-are-not-reflexive), [Dual of $l^\infty$ is not $l^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868787/dual-of-l-infty-is-not-l1) and more), and all proofs stop after showing that there exists $f \in (l^\infty)' \cong (l^1)''$ that is not representable as
\begin{equation} f(x) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i x_i \quad \text{with} \quad a \in l^1 \end{equation}
like the Hahn-Banach extension of $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ on $c \subseteq l^\infty$.

With the isometric, linear injection $X \to X'', x \mapsto (\phi \mapsto \phi(x))$ we get that $l^1 \subsetneq (l^1)''$, but why does it follow from this that $l^1 \not\cong (l^1)''$? After all, there are spaces that are isometrically isomorphic to proper subspaces of themselves, like $l^1 \cong X := \{ x \in l^1 | x_1 = 0 \} \subsetneq l^1$ by
\begin{equation}
\phi: l^1 \to X, \quad (x_1, x_2, x_3, ...) \mapsto (0, x_1, x_2, ...)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By **definition** a normed linear space $X$ is reflexive if  the canonical injection from $X$ to the second dual is surjective.

For the definition see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: So there could still be a continuous, linear bijection between $l^1$ and $(l^1)''$?

Comment: But that is not the definition of reflexivity. It does not matter if there is an isomorphism between $X$ and $X''$. Your confusion is with the definition of reflexivity. @Feanor